# TableView with NSFetchedResultController displays corrupted cells outside the screen

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, uitableview, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I have `UITableView` showing Core Data items, previously hooked through an array without any issues. I then moved to `CoreDataTableViewController` as per Apple and Stanford suggestion to integrate Core Data with `UITableView` directly through `NSFetchedResultsController`. I have added the `CoreDataTableViewController` to my project and changed the super class of my original TVC to be the new CDTVC.

I am now having issues with cells outside of the screen, some of them are gray with wrong data on it. It has probably something to do with reusing of those cells, but I can't figure out the solution. Any ideas? Thank you.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    // Configure the cell...
    Period *displayPeriod = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
    dateFormatter.timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"GMT"];
    [dateFormatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle];
    cell.textLabel.text = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:displayPeriod.date];

    NSError *error = nil;
    NSUInteger logbookCount = [self.managedObjectContext countForFetchRequest:self.fetchedResultsController.fetchRequest error:&error];

    if (indexPath.row == logbookCount - 1) {
        cell.detailTextLabel.text = @"";
    } else {
        int difference;

        NSIndexPath *nextRow = [NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:indexPath.row + 1 inSection:indexPath.section];

        Period *periodOne = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:nextRow];
        Period *periodTwo = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];

        difference = [self dateDiffrenceFromDate:periodOne.date second:periodTwo.date];
        cell.detailTextLabel.text = [self formatDifferenceToString:difference];
        if (difference > 45 || difference < 21) {
            cell.detailTextLabel.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:255/255.0 green:59/255.0 blue:48/255.0 alpha:1.0];
        } else {
            cell.detailTextLabel.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:142/255.0 green:142/255.0 blue:147/255.0 alpha:1.0];
        }
    }
    return cell;
}
```

Screenshot:

[image: screenshot1]

Comment: Could you provide a screenshot? In addition, formatter are expensive to create. Just create once and reuse it!!!

Comment: Also resue colors, you will notice a boost on performances.

Comment: I see I should move the dateformatter and colors out. I'll do it for sure. Please see the screenshot. One line on the end of the list is gray and has no date and distance on it. Even if I comment everything from the cellforrow atindexpath out and leave just create cell and display static text, the cell will loook the same - empty without the text.

Comment: Are you talking about the penultimate row? Have you tried to output log values to see what date formatters outputs?

Comment: Yes, it's the penultimate row. It took some time to output logs and test it. The logs says the data are ok. Correct count of records and correct values, even the days difference. It is for sure visual. When I add 11th row (on 4-inch iPhone) which is exactly on the edge of the visible tableview, the table adds the weird gray cell underneath. When I continue adding dates, the ones that should be displayed on that gray row are not visible, but logs shows correct values.

Comment: Are you using registerClass method to creatina cells?

Comment: Could you also init the int value to zero? I am talking about difference. Just to be sure ;)

Comment: I was not using registerClass, but when I added it, there was no difference. Also with the zero init value for difference ;) Still having the ghost cell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Such an idiot. The ghost line was actually a UIToolBar. A commented-out code from an early prototype that I accidently uncommented and therefore added the ToolBar in viewDidLoad. When the number of rows reached the edge of the screen, the ToolBar finally appeared underneath the TabBar and started to scroll with the other rows in tableview. From now on I will delete all old code periodically to avoid such a stupid mistake.

Comment: You're welcome. Happy to see you solved the problem. +1 for coming back with your answer. Do not forget to mark as asnwered.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what happens in your case. Based on my comments and your answers, you don't see any error in Core Data related stuff. Anyway I cannot see any code related to cell creation. In addition, you said that your are not using `registerClass` method. Hence I would try two solutions.

Using `registerClass` in a explicit manner (starting from iOS 6).

```
- (void) viewDidLoad {
   [super viewDidLoad];

   [self.tableView registerClass:[UITableViewCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier ];
}
```

Or just create your cell with an if clause.

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
if(!cell) {
    cell = // create the cell here
}

// configure the cell here
```

Comment: Tried all. I didn't had the issue on a prototype project with NSFetchedResultController that I created before injecting NSFRC into the main project. So I imported the CDTVC subclass from that project and it worked well. So I compared every line and found a stupid mistake. The ghost line was actually a ToolBar that I accidently un-commented and therefore added in viewDidLoad. When the rows reached the edge of screen, the ToolBar appeared underneath the TabBar and started to scroll with the rows. Thanks very much for all your help and effort.